# Asp.net Mvc: Filters nullable parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nullable

I am trying to use a nullable datetime and double as a parameter for an actionfilter but it's gives the following error:

> 'Propertyname' is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type

I thought a quick google would solve it but to my surpise I couldn't find a lot of info about it.

Here is the code of my filter.

```
public class AddToSitemap : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Changefreq { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lastmod { get; set; }
    public double? Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the class name be AddToSiteMapAttribute for MVC Framework to pick up the attribute correctly?

Comment: That's actually a good question, all the examples I've seen do it too. My code seems to work so I am not sure if it's mandatory to add Attribute to the name.

Comment: It is not mandatory but it is world-wide accepted guideline and rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [the compiler error on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kk5syz6(VS.71).aspx).

You can only use following types according to [Attributes Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(VS.71).aspx#vcwlkattributestutorialanchor1):

> Attribute parameters are restricted to
>   constant values of the following
>   types:
>
> ```
> - Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
> - string
> - System.Type
> - enums
> - object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above types.)
> * One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types
> ```

Which means you in your case that cannot use:

1. Nullable Double.
2. Nullable DateTime.
3. DateTime.

I would advice to use *int* or *enumeration* for the Priority as priority doesn't sound to be a good candidate for beeing Double.

You can *workaround DateTime by changing its type to long* and assigning Ticks to it.
But I *doubt that C# allows you to assign non-constant values* for attributes when applying them (and new DateTime(1234,5,6).Ticks is not a constant from that perspective).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a string instead and convert that to DateTime in your action method or ViewModel, etc.